# Почему на кнопке не появляется заданное изображение? (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qpushbutton, qicon

У меня есть список, в котором хранятся изображения, которые я хочу разместить на кнопках.

Когда пытаюсь прикрепить эти изображения к кнопкам, кнопки остаются пустыми.
Картинки с такими названиями есть и расположены в папке с кодом.

Пожалуйста, подскажите, что я делаю неправильно?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

list1 = ['picture1.png', 'picture2.png']

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Button")
        self.box1 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.box1.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(self.box1)
        self.pictures()

    def pictures(self):
        self.box2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        for picture in list1:
            self.button_picture = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
            self.button_picture.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(picture))
            self.button_picture.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 100))
            self.box2.addWidget(self.button_picture)
        self.box1.addLayout(self.box2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Они в той же папке, что этот код?

Comment: Да, я уточнил об этом в вопросе. В названиях не ошибся

Comment: У меня такое ощущение, что ошибка в самих картинках. Они в каком-нибудь viewer'е открываются?

Comment: Открываются, в самом VSCode(я пишу тут код) их можно просмотреть

Comment: Вы запускаете программу из другого каталога. Зайдите в каталог где лежать изображения и запустите модуль от туда.

Comment: У меня работает, правда с jpeg.

Comment: @S.Nick, возможно что-то не понимаю, но запускаю программу в самом VSCode, т.е. из папки, где лежат изображения

Comment: я вам очень советую запускать программы из `терминала/CMD` и еще уберите `self`  из названия переменной `self.button_picture`

Comment: чтобы убедиться откуда вы запускаете программу добавьте в самом начале модуля `import os; print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: @S.Nick, я открыл каталог, где лежат картинки и код, с помощью cmd и запустил код. Результат не изменился

Comment: открыли - это уже хорошо. Теперь наберите в командной строке `python main.py`

Comment: @S.Nick, если что, файл с кодом, который я оставил выше, называется test4.py. Я уже запустил его так, как вы сказали. Кнопки остались пустыми. Сейчас взял код из самого простого примера добавления картинки на кнопку. Кнопка тоже остается пустой

Comment: чтобы убедиться откуда вы запускаете программу добавьте в самом начале модуля `import os; print(os.getcwd())` - что выводит print ?

Comment: @S.Nick, cmd ничего не выводит, молча открывает окно. VSCode выводит нужную мне папку

Comment: @S.Nick, прошу прощения, обманул. CMD выводит нужную папку тоже

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы запускаете программу из другого каталога. Зайдите в каталог где лежать изображения и запустите модуль от туда.

я вам очень советую запускать программы из `терминала/CMD` и еще уберите `self` из названия переменной `self.button_picture`

чтобы убедиться откуда вы запускаете программу добавьте в самом начале модуля

```
import os 
print(os.getcwd())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

list1 = ['im.png', 'Ok.png']

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Button")
        self.box1 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.box1.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(self.box1)
        self.pictures()

    def pictures(self):
        self.box2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        for picture in list1:
            button_picture = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
            button_picture.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(picture))
            button_picture.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 100))
            self.box2.addWidget(button_picture)
        self.box1.addLayout(self.box2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Каталог правильный:) Что-то с компьютером моим. Запустил этот код на другом компьютере, все заработало

Comment: Не знаете, что в таких ситуациях делают? Может PyQt5 переустановить?

Comment: @MAXIM045  а что вы получаете если заменить на `list1 = ['D:/_Qt/__Qt/im.png', 'D:/_Qt/__Qt/Ok.png']`, т.е. указать полный путь.

Comment: Окно с пустыми кнопками:(

Comment: Попробуйте создать `новый каталог` Перенести туда `test4.py` и `картинки`. Запустите `python test4`.py  из командной строки из этого каталога.

Comment: Снова окно с пустыми кнопками

Comment: я переустановил PyQt и теперь все работает

Comment: @MAXIM045  `Всё, что ни делается, всё к лучшему`. Я думаю, что вы узнали новые вещи для себя :)

Answer (score 1):

Как уже вам написали, проблема в относительном пути к картинкам и т.к. активная директория у вас была другая, то и картинки не нашлись.

Решением может быть указание полного пути к картинкам относительно текущей папки файла.

Берем [специальную функцию](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/935355df1d4385e16e1eea3e57ce61024e7e2e02/get_current_script_dir.py#L13):

```
import inspect
import os
import sys


def get_current_script_dir(follow_symlinks=True, normcase=False) -> str:
    # py2exe, PyInstaller, cx_Freeze
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        path = os.path.abspath(sys.executable)
    else:
        # Analog inspect.getabsfile without os.path.normcase
        path = inspect.getframeinfo(inspect.currentframe()).filename
        path = os.path.abspath(path)

    if follow_symlinks:
        path = os.path.realpath(path)

    if normcase:
        path = os.path.normcase(path)

    return os.path.dirname(path)
```

И используем ее так, чтобы получить полный путь к картинкам:

```
DIR = get_current_script_dir()

list1 = [DIR + '/picture1.png', DIR + '/picture2.png']

# Проверьте пути
print(list1)
```

Comment: @MAXIM045, ничего страшного :) А, кст, вы проверяли пути с моим ответом? У картинок пути совпадают и они отображаются?

Comment: Я получил такой список: ['c:\\Users\\101ap\\Desktop\\Новая папка/picture1.png', 'c:\\Users\\101ap\\Desktop\\Новая папка/picture2.png']. Названия папок и файлов правильные, но слеши надо поравить, это я умею:)

Comment: Я переустановил PyQt и теперь все работает